# How add another EditText when I click and fill another ( Android )

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-edittext

I was googling for a while but I can't find the way how to add a another EditText after I click on one.

I try to describe my problem by this picture:

[image]

Is there a some container providing this functionality ?

Comment: You need specific number of edit text or depend on use input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout holder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
        //get a reference to the LinearLayout - the holder of our views
        holder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.holder);
        addNewEdit();
    }

    private void addNewEdit() {
        //inflate a new EditText from the layout
        final EditText newEdit = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_edit, holder, false);
        //add it to the holder
        holder.addView(newEdit);
        //set the text change lisnter
        newEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //here we decide if we have to add a new EditText view or to
                //remove the current
                if (s.length() == 0 && holder.getChildCount() > 1) {
                    holder.removeView(newEdit);
                } else if (s.length() > 0 && ((before + start) == 0)) {
                    addNewEdit();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `your_activity.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

And the `new_edit.xml`:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

</EditText>
```

EDIT: Of course, you have to set you correct paddings/margins, and probably create you own and styled layouts for the holder and the items that you inflate.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all 5 to your XML and assign `android:visibility="gone"` to all but first one. You then need to assign a TextWatcher to each one off them, but for the simplicity I will only show it for one.

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                et2.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                // The rest of them also???
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

If you do not want a fixed number of them, you will want to programmatically create EditTexts and then adding them to one of the ViewGroups (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout, ...) by calling `addView` method